# Best approach to display the image after it is loaded

Tags: javascript

Currently I see there are two ways we can show the image after it is loaded.

**First Approach**

```
<img id="myImage" />

var img = new Image(),
    x = document.getElementById("myImage");

img.onload = function() {
   x.src = img.src;
};

img.src = "http://somedomain/image.jpg";
```

**Second Approach**

```
<img id="myImage" src="http://somedomain/image.jpg" style="display:none" onload="showImage();" />

function showImage() {
  document.getElementById("myImage").style.display = 'block';
}
```

I'm little confused which one is the better approach? In some examples I found online they uses the first approach but I see the second approach is very simple. Is there any drawbacks exist in the second approach?

Comment: I'll say first use some `loading...` image and when actual image is loaded replace it.

Comment: First one is fine if you have only one image into consideration.. For multiple images, second one is more suitable.. But as far a performance is concerned, I doubt there is any difference as both the approaches make use of `onload` event.. And yes, use `pre-loader`(`css`/light-weight gif) for better UX as suggested by Tushar..

Comment: Another approach could using `data-src` attributes to hold `src` of the images.. Looping through all the images and setting the `src` when image is `loaded`..

Answer (score 1):

**First approach** is better from a **re-usability of code** point of view.

You can use the `img` variable for other images as well if multiple `Img` tags are going to point to the same images such as showing delete icon for line items.

**Second approach** is better from the point of view of **usability**.

You can show a different (already available) image like loading or a default user-avatar till the image is actually downloaded and available.

Also, with the second approach you can fade-in or slide-up images when the onload event is invoked, which you can't do with first approach.

Comment: Displaying a loading image is possible only using the first approach rgt? We don't want the onload event firing up for the loading image.

Comment: @Mark You can hide the image by default and show a loading image. When the actual image onload has been invoked, show the same and hide the `loading` image. So yes, it can be done with second approach only.

Comment: @Mark Onload event for `loading` image shouldn't hurt since this approach is supposed to be used only for fetching images which content images (not application images like delete or arrow icon). Also, by using site manifest (application cache) you can prefetch those images which are not content.

Answer (score 1):

**First approach first.**

In the first approach, no image source is defined initially and is being defined later, which makes it a good approach to load multiples images, so that the other parts of the document can be rendered first and fast.
This is the similar approach used by lazy load plugins triggered by on scroll event.
It is a good practice when you have a no. of images to load on your web page.

But it has a disadvantage, your images won't be SEO friendly and will fail W3C standard tests as web bots won't be able to crawl your images in the absence of img source.

**Second approach** is displaying the already loaded image which is a slower process in terms of speed of document loading than the first approach. Js is playing with css here which is generally used to animate image display.

Unlike, first approach, images are SEO friendly as they can be crawled by web spiders and indexed.